# I want to use string value as variable name, and the variable have to global variable

Tags: c#, string, variables, global

Searching in "stack overflow",
I am coding below for string value as variable name.

```
var ESScommand = new Dictionary<string, ESS_command>();
ESScommand[sample.Data.ESS_name] = new ESS_command();
ESScommand[sample.Data.ESS_name] = sample.Data;
```

But I want to ESScommand[sample.Data.ESS_name] as global variable.
Is it possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as a global variable, but it is simple to make it a global property.

```
static class Globals
{
    public static ESS_command GlobalCommand => ESScommand[sample.Data.ESS_name];
}
```

To access:

```
var cmd = Globals.GlobalCommand;
```